# Controller other than Home will not pass MvcIntegrationTesting tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, integration-testing

I am using an [adaptation](https://github.com/JonCanning/MvcIntegrationTestFramework/) of Steve Sanderson's wonderful [MVC Integration Testing Framework](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/).

If I take any view in my application and serve it through this framework (which basically creates a 'fake' worker request through [`HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.processrequest.aspx)) I can host it within the ASP.NET Runtime in the context of my integration test.

My question is why would any view from the `HomeController` go nicely through this process but any other controller give a response with

> Path 'get' is forbidden

I can move any view to the HomeController and test it without issue. I see no difference (url not withstanding) of the worker request fake between the two calls. I am at a loss!

Stack trace in test output:

> ContentControllerTwitterReturnsTheTwitterView :
>   FailedSystem.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>
> Server stack trace:  at
>   website.tests.ContentControllerTwitterTests.b__0(BrowsingSession
>   session) at
>   MvcIntegrationTestFramework.Hosting.AppDomainProxy.RunBrowsingSessionInAppDomain(SerializableDelegate`1
>   script) in AppDomainProxy.cs: line 19 at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:  at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(ref
>   MessageData msgData, Int32 type) at
>   MvcIntegrationTestFramework.Hosting.AppDomainProxy.RunBrowsingSessionInAppDomain(SerializableDelegate`1
>   script) at MvcIntegrationTestFramework.Hosting.AppHost.Start(Action`1
>   testScript) in AppHost.cs: line 34 at
>   website.tests.ContentControllerTwitterTests.ContentControllerTwitterReturnsTheTwitterView()
>   in HomeControllerTwitterTests.cs: line 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was naming ... answer is

> *Do not name your controllers with same name as a folder within solution!*

Old fool :)